# Show video file from CD card using HTML5 video tag in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

I load `*.mp4` file to CD card into `/data/data/package_name/cache` directory.

If I use `webView.loadUrl("/data/data/package_name/cache/filename.mp4")` - it works.

But I want to show it inside WebView, using `<video>` HTML5 tag:

`<video src="file:///data/data/package_name/cache/filename.mp4"></video>`

According to [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/76ef458065798bc70114854cf4b51827005448a1/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/MediaResourceGetter.java) `MediaResourceGetter` acceptable filePathes are:
`/mnt/sdcard/`, `/sdcard/` and `"/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/cache/"` otherwise will be `Refusing to read from unsafe file location` error, if `file://` scheme used.

Hardware acceleration turned on for this activity, all settings like `setWebChromeClient`, `setWebViewClient` and settings like `setJavaScriptEnabled`, `setPluginState`, `setAllowFileAccess` also turned on.
`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission also present.

I tried to show this `*.mp4` file in WebView using `loadUrl`, `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL` but video does not play - just video icon.
(I have tested on Nexus 4 with Android 5.1, and other content from html is displayed).

No errors or warnings in logcat, just this:

```
D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ canonicalized file path: /data/data/com.myapp/cache/filename.mp4
D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ resource has video
D/MediaResourceGetter﹕ extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=12804, width=480, height=198, success=true]
```

I have found [the same problem](https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3046/android-html5-videos-in-web-views-will-no-longer-play), but without solution.

How to show it in `WebView` using `<view>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Link1: [webview cannot load html file from sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473601/webview-cannot-load-html-file-from-sd-card)

Link2: [Android webview loading html5 page from SD card with mp4 videos on various API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316127/android-webview-loading-html5-page-from-sd-card-with-mp4-videos-on-various-api)

Link3: [Unable to play video in html using webview from sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293053/unable-to-play-video-in-html-using-webview-from-sdcard)